# Convert string to html tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to convert the following string to HTML tags and place it inside my div.

```
&lt;strong&gt;asdfadfsafsd&lt;/strong&gt;
```

I am using the following code to place it inside my div:

```
var message = "&lt;strong&gt;testmessage&lt;/strong&gt";
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = bericht;
```

The problem is that I see the following in my div now:

```
<strong>testmessage</strong>
```

But I want to see:
**testmessage**

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var string = "&lt;strong&gt;asdfadfsafsd&lt;/strong&gt;",
    results = document.getElementById("results")
    results.innerHTML = string;
    results.innerHTML =    results.textContent;
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

At first load the it as html. Then fetch it as text and then again load it as HTML :)

[Refer HTML Entities](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Comment: and a link to HTML character entities : http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: Easy and simple! Just what I needed!

Comment: You're welcome :) Also refer to that link by @Kaiido as well. It will be useful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `createElement`

```
var tag = document.createElement("strong");
var t = document.createTextNode("testmessage");
tag.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(tag);
```