# Convert string to HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I have a string being sent to my JavaScript function from my C# code which has a text like:

```
 Hi <b>Welcome to C#<sup>5.0</sup></b>
```

I'm populating a div with this string. I need this html content to be rendered in the screen with the bold and superscript applied as below

> Hi **Welcome to C#<sup>5.0</sup>**

I tried the below it just displays the HTML tags as plain text

```
myfunction = function(data) {
  var mytext = '<div>'+ data +'</div>;
  $('#mydivid').after(mytext);
}
```

Is there any other solution neither like the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394748/whats-the-right-way-to-decode-a-string-that-has-special-html-entities-in-it) nor [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576558/convert-string-to-html-tags-in-javascript) ?

Note: I **cannot** declare the string in a hidden variable in my .cshtml file within @HTML.Raw and again use it in my JavaScript.

I have tried using `$.parseHTML` but I got an error saying

```
$.parseHTML is not a function
```

Any solution other than the above solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've tagged this question as `jquery`, so why aren't you using the `html()` function?

Comment: and more importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: you can directly replace this line `var mytext = '<div>'+ data +'</div>;` with razor syntax `var mytext = '<div>'+ '@Html.Raw(data)' +'</div>;` ... As you said `I cannot declare the string in a hidden variable` .. so with this syntax there is no need of variable

Comment: @RajshekarReddy are you telling me include Html.Raw in my .js file. Is that possible? No right?

Comment: @SethuBala oh... I didnt know the code was in a JS file.. then that wont work..

Comment: @SethuBala but still there is a plugin which enables the power to use Razor syntax in .js file https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Is there any other way rather than adding a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like nothing is wrong with your code. Check if some css is overriding the basic `em` and `sup` functionality.

for Example the default style of `em` is `font-style: italic` which chould be override by your css

Comment: Yeah! You were right. I had to override my css. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
myfunction = function(data) {
  $('#mydivid').html('<div>' + data + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: This solution will work well for replacing .append() (sorry that was a late edit in my question) with .html() but in my case I'm using .after(). So what should I do for this case.

Comment: try like this $('#mydivid').after('<div>' + data + '</div>');

Comment: Tried but no improvement

Answer (score 1):

You listed JQuery in your tags so I figured this would help.

```
html = $.parseHTML(  'Hi <b>Welcome to C#<sup>5.0</sup></b>' );
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michael_coder/7tdtfyj9/)

You can also do this if you want a javascript oneliner.

```
document.getElementById("mydivid").innerHTML="Hi <b>Welcome to C#<sup>5.0</sup></b>";
```

Comment: Tried this solution already and got error as "$.parseHTML is not a function"

Comment: Are you sure you have Jquery included in your scripts?

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty sure about that :)

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: jQuery version "1.7.1"

Comment: parseHTML was added in 1.8

Comment: Try this         document.getElementById("mydivid").innerHTML="Hi <b>Welcome to C#<sup>5.0</sup></b>";

Comment: You can also do += if you want to append html